# Spinnaker: URLRedirection cannot recognize subpath

Tags: spinnaker

I know its experimental, I am trying to setup use docker-compose to build Spinnaker. I am seeing an error when trying to browse localhost:9000. Its trying to redirect to this page.

```
http://localhost:8084/auth/redirectto=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9000%2F%23%2Finfrastructure
```

Looks like either its a fiat or gate issue. Tried adding proxy to apache2.

Errors in Fiat:

```
RetrofitError: unexpected url: front50/serviceAccounts
2017-09-15 19:24:31.642  WARN 1 --- [ont50Service-10] 
c.n.s.f.p.internal.Front50Service        : [] Falling back to service 
account cache. Cause: unexpected url: front50/serviceAccounts
2017-09-15 19:24:31.645  WARN 1 --- [ecutionAction-1] 
c.n.s.fiat.roles.UserRolesSyncer         : [] User permission sync 
failed. Server status is DOWN. Trying again in 10000 ms. Cause:
(Provider: DefaultServiceAccountProvider) retrofit.RetrofitError: 
unexpected url: front50/serviceAccounts
```

Errors in gate:

```
2017-09-15 19:18:19.386 ERROR 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] 
o.s.b.b.PropertiesConfigurationFactory   : Properties configuration 
failed validation
2017-09-15 19:18:19.394 ERROR 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] 
o.s.b.b.PropertiesConfigurationFactory   : Field error in object 
'target' on field 'services[ORCA_HOST]': rejected value [orca]; codes
```

Comment: This looks like a DNS issue - are you overriding `baseUrls` with just values like `front50` and `orca`?

Answer (score 0):

For errors in fiat, you can  configure the environment variable in docker compose to

```
environment:
    - "SERVICES_CLOUDDRIVER_BASEURL=http://clouddriver:7002"
    - "SERVICES_FRONT50_BASEURL=http://front50:8080"
```

Update: This workaround work for Gate

```
environment:
    - "services.clouddriver.host=clouddriver"
    - "services.echo.host=echo"
    - "services.front50.host=front50"
    - "services.igor.host=igor"
    - "services.orca.host=orca"
    - "services.rosco.host=rosco"
```